# How to automatically close swipe after swiping another row in android?

Tags: android

What i am trying to achieve is that I am using view pager inside Recycler view for swiping. Now i am able to get the present position of swiped row. Now what i want achieve is that for example i have swiped row 1 to left and then if i swipe the row 2 to left the row 1 should automatically swiped right.
How can i achieve this.

This is my viewPager onTouch listener :

```
holder.viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        presentPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();

        if(globalPosition == presentPosition) {

            //do nothing

            System.out.println("present position equal is  " + globalPosition);

        } else {

            //close the previous swipe

            ManageCustomerModelObject modelObject = ManageCustomerModelObject.values()[0];
            modelObject.setmLayoutResId(0);

            System.out.println("present position not equal is  " + globalPosition);

            globalPosition = presentPosition;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

This is my view Pager Adapter code snippet :

```
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        System.out.println("viewpager position " + patientPosition);

        ManageCustomerModelObject modelObject = ManageCustomerModelObject.values()[position];
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
        collection.addView(layout);
}
```

This is my modelObejct code :

```
public enum ManageCustomerModelObject {

    BEFORE_SWIPE(R.string.before_swipe, R.layout.before_swipe),
    AFTER_SWIPE(R.string.after_swipe, R.layout.after_swipe);

    public int mTitleResId;
    public int mLayoutResId;

     ManageCustomerModelObject(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
        mTitleResId = titleResId;
        mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
    }

    public void setmLayoutResId(int mLayoutResId) {
        this.mLayoutResId = mLayoutResId;
    }

    public int getTitleResId() {
        return mTitleResId;
    }

    public int getLayoutResId() {
        return mLayoutResId;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position)` for that in `onPageChangeListener`

Comment: In view Pager Adapter?

Comment: No. In your activity

Comment: View Pager is inside the Recycler view. So i am not getting onPageChangeListner

Comment: I have tried this.It's working but not as i expected